# Compilation Erro - Azure - CS0103

Tags: microsoft-azure

Estou com um problema para hospedar um website MVC 5, em meu VS2013 funciona no *localhost* normalmente, tudo 100%, mas ao fazer o upload para um servidor aparece esse erro:

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the
>   current context

Ai pensei que pudesse ser algo com o `RoutUrl`, só que ao tentar acessar manualmente outro link aparece o mesmo erro com o mesmo código só que situação diferente:

> CS0103: The name 'TempData' does not exist in the current context

ou

> CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Todos os *assemblies* estão atualizados e tudo funciona no *localhost*, não consigo reproduzir esse erro.

Já fiz testes em dois servidores diferentes e estão dando o mesmo erro. Neste momento estou usando o AZURE onde o deploy deixa tudo muito mais simples....

Alguém saberia o porque disso? Imagino que seja alguma referência. Sendo que algum tempo atrás eu já havia feito um teste no Azure também e tudo funcionou. Agora depois de algumas atualizações que começou a dar esse erro em um novo cadastro que fiz pra ser o definitivo.

Answer (score 0):

@William, veja se nas referencias do projeto, a dll System.Web está como Copy Local: True. Veja também, nas configurações do seu website/webapp se a versão do .NET Framework é a mesmo que vc está subindo.